# Combining retrieved values with javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I Convert a String into an Integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript)

I have a select element that contains options for products. What I want to achieve is when they pick an option the price on the page automatically adjusts. I have figured out how to retrieve those values but when I combine them it just puts two numbers together instead of actually adding them.

For example instead of outputting 60 when I have 50 + 10 it outputs 5010.

My code:

```
$('.product_options').change(function(){
var base_price = $('#base_price').html();
var add_price = $(this).find("option:selected").data('price');

var new_price = base_price+add_price;

console.log(new_price);

$('.current_price').html(base_price+add_price);
```

});

Is there a way I can convert them both to integers so the operation actually goes through?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use some tricks like multiplying by 1 to force a number cast or you can use parseInt()

Answer (score 5):

Use `parseInt`

```
$('.product_options').change(function(){
var base_price = parseInt($('#base_price').html(), 10); // 10 as second argument will make sure that base is 10.
var add_price = parseInt($(this).find("option:selected").data('price'), 10);

var new_price = base_price+add_price;

console.log(new_price);

$('.current_price').html(base_price+add_price);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var base_price = +$('#base_price').html();
var add_price = +$(this).find("option:selected").data('price');
```

See the mighty: [Mozilla's Arithmetic Operators Reference - Unary Negation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Negation.29)

Comment: I had no idea..! Does this work on all browsers?

Comment: @BillyMoon: It's part of the EMCAScript specification.

Answer (score 0):

Any values you pull out of the DOM are going to be strings, and need converting into number types before you can do mathematical operations with them.

`parseInt( ... )` is a built in javascript function that converts a string into an integer, if the string consists of digits only.

If you need a decimal number, you can use `parseFlaot`.

```
var new_price = parseInt(base_price)+parseInt(add_price);
// new_price is now set to the sum of `base_price` and `add_price`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parseFloat or parseInt

```
$('.product_options').change(function(){
  var base_price = $('#base_price').html();
  var add_price = $(this).find("option:selected").data('price');

  var new_price = parseFloat(base_price) + parseFloat(add_price);

  console.log(new_price);

  $('.current_price').html(base_price+add_price);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

```
intval = parseInt(string)
```

is what you're looking for.